# Should code in examples be copy-paste-able?

Tags: discussion, documentation

### Should code in examples be copy-paste-able (as a working program)?

#### Yes

- Reader can just copy-paste a working solution and try it out for themselves
- Saves the read headaches if his program doesn't work, because he implemented the solution wrongly (forgot to `#include`, `import`, ...)

#### No

- Examples are way to long if they should work out-of-the-box
- Distracts from main objective (Showing how a specific problem should be solved)
- 90% of people are only interested in a solution, not a working program (they would probably only copy-paste the 3 line solution, instead of the working program)
- Unnecessary - Everyone should know how to write a working program (if not, they shouldn't start sorting arrays)

<sub>Some arguments only apply to some languages (like C++, Java) and not to others (Python, ...)</sub>

I vote for **No**. I think it is unnecessary to write a full program.

<sub>Actual code from an actual examples in an actual topic in an actual tag :)</sub>

---

[...]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::multimap<int, std::string, std::greater<int>> sorted_map;
    // Sort the names of animals in descending order of the number of legs
    sorted_map.insert(std::make_pair(6,   "bug"));
    sorted_map.insert(std::make_pair(4,   "cat"));
    sorted_map.insert(std::make_pair(100, "centipede"));
    sorted_map.insert(std::make_pair(2,   "chicken"));
    sorted_map.insert(std::make_pair(0,   "fish"));
    sorted_map.insert(std::make_pair(4,   "horse"));
    sorted_map.insert(std::make_pair(8,   "spider"));

    for (auto const& entry: sorted_map)
    {
        std::cout << entry.second << " (has " << entry.first << " legs)" << '\n';
    }
}
```

[...]

---

The only difference between sorting in descending order (above) rather than ascending is just one argument: `std::greater<int>`.

Also, the example above also doesn't compile, it misses `#include <functional>`.

I would definitely rewrite to something like:

---

[...]

```
//'sorted_map' sorts its keys in descending order
std::multimap<int, std::string, std::greater<>> sorted_map;

sorted_map.emplace(1, "bar");
sorted_map.emplace(5, "foo");

std::string value = sorted_map.begin()->second; 
//'value' is "foo", because  keys are sorted in descending order, and so 5 comes before 1
```

[...]

---

In my opinion, the second code-snippet is much better, for the reasons stated above. This might not be a problem for small code-snippets, but when you start having multiple `#include`s (and other stuff) the program gets longer and longer (as this one).

What should we encourage?

Comment: I vote for straight copy and paste examples like cppreference does.  If someone is using this stuff to learn they may not know what includes to include.  They should be able to just copy, paste, compile and run.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Depends** :).

We should not *require* examples to be "copy-pasteable".

Sometimes you have an example, and the only important part is showing, say, a difference in syntax. I wonder what the benefit would be in, say, [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/208/comparison-operations/2110/abstract-vs-strict-equality-and-operators) regarding equality operators in JavaScript. Here's an excerpt:

> ```
>  var a = '', 
>      b = 0, 
>      c = '0';
>  a == b; // true
>  b == c; // true
>  a == c; // false
> ```

We *could* add `console.log()` or `console.assert()` around each of those equality comparisons, but that distracts from the example code itself.

If the example warrants a compilable, runnable example, sure. Or if your language of choice requires certain ceremonies to have a successful example (e.g., the `#include` statements from the OP), sure.

So I would vote for a more nuanced approach of "where it makes sense".

Comment: Couldn't agree more, also worth pointing that if need arises for a "copy-pasteable" programs we could always point to some kind of "live @..."  examples like this topic is doing: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays/404/creating-and-initializing-arrays
if you scroll down you'll see a button "live on ideone" with the full code but just the meat of the example is on the topic itself.